# Rails4 order method does not work in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pg

i created a method like below

```
def sort_by_footprints
  joins(:footprints).group(:article_id).order('SUM(articles.id) DESC')
end
```

but this doesn't work  when i use postgresql and it says
`ActionView::Template::Error (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "articles.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
joins(:footprints).group(:article_id).select('SUM(articles.id) as total_articles').order('total_articles DESC')
```

Comment: This is just what i want! Thnx!! ;)